# Maximum and minimum against strings

Tags: vba, excel

I have data as shown:
http://bit.ly/1O6aaWX

For each department I have to calculate minimum, maximum wait time and if possible, average time too. The no. of departments can be dynamic. I have got no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Using the following as an example:

### [image]

You need to use `SUMIF()` to get the total in column E

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php

In your case you need the following (row 2):

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,"=" & D2,$C$2:$C$11)
```

Then `COUNTIF` in column F (row 2):

https://support.office.com/en-za/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B11,"="&D2)
```

Average is obviously sum/count!

And then you can use the following information to work out the max and min ... http://www.contextures.com/excelminmaxfunction.html#minif

By placing the department name in column D, and referencing it in the `SUMIF\COUNTIF` forumals, you can create a list of departments as long as you want!

---

**NOTE** the `MINIF` example is an array formula ... best look that up first if you've never used one before ...  http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/array-formulas.html

---

If you really must use VBA, then this will work for the example worksheet i've shown at the top of this post ...

```
Sub CalculateStuff()

Dim dDepartmentTotals(4) As Integer
Dim dDepartmentMinimum(4) As Integer: For i = 1 To 4: dDepartmentMinimum(i) = 32767: Next i
Dim dDepartmentMaximum(4) As Integer
Dim dDepartmentAverage(4) As Integer
Dim dDepartmentCount(4) As Integer

For i = 2 To 11

    ideptno = CInt(Right(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2), 1))
    dDepartmentTotals(ideptno) = dDepartmentTotals(ideptno) + Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3)
    If dDepartmentMaximum(ideptno) < Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) Then dDepartmentMaximum(ideptno) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3)
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) < dDepartmentMinimum(ideptno) Then dDepartmentMinimum(ideptno) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3)
    dDepartmentCount(ideptno) = dDepartmentCount(ideptno) + 1
Next i

For i = 1 To 4

    dDepartmentAverage(i) = dDepartmentTotals(i) \ dDepartmentCount(i)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it in vba?

Comment: Which bit? All this can be solved via formulas! Not that I'm against vba ... it's just that formulas never crash so i only use vba when i need to!

Comment: I would have explained to you why I need to use vba but let's not get to that. Is there any way I can do it using VBA

Comment: I've added a vba version ... i really would like to know why you have to use vba though?! :0)

Comment: The code is showing subscript out of range on: dDepartmentTotals(ideptno) = dDepartmentTotals(ideptno) + Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3). Btw did I add that the no. of departments can be dynamic.

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/array.html ... everything you need to know about arrays. I think it's only fair you do some of the work.